# Why when hovering sprite on DataVisualization the Card Position not correctly in center?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I try to perform a Sprite using DataViz Extension. However the position of the Info Card is not correct when I zoom it.

[image]

Here is my Code

```
onSpriteHovering(event) {
    const hovered = event.hovering;
    if (hovered) {
      const firstDbId = event.dbId;
      const model = event.target.model;
      const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
      const fragList = model.getFragmentList();
      let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
      instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
        firstDbId,
        (fragId) => {
          let box = new THREE.Box3();
          fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, box);
          bounds.union(box);
        },
        true
      );
      this.posModel = bounds.getCenter();
      const dataSprite = {
        id: firstDbId,
      };
      this.infoChart.showIcon(firstDbId, dataSprite, this.posModel);
      // this.infoChart.makeChart();
    } else {
      this.infoChart.clearInfoChart();
    }
  }
```

Updating Position :

```
  updateIcons() {
    if (this.infoChart && this.posModel) {
      const pos = this.viewer.worldToClient(this.posModel);
      this.infoChart.style.left = `${Math.floor(
        100 + pos.x - this.infoChart.offsetWidth / 2
      )}px`;
      this.infoChart.style.top = `${Math.floor(
        100 + pos.y - this.infoChart.offsetWidth / 2
      )}px`;
    }
  }
```

Comment: it might be related to the offset values you passed to your info chart. You may refer to here to see how DataViz CustomTooltip handles this: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/blob/main/client/components/BaseApp.jsx#L608

Comment: BTW, here is an example demonstrating how to use DataViz react components in Vanilla Javascript: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components-es5

Comment: After I `console.log` the position after worldToClient() the value really small, so it make sense if the card not centering the sprite. I still don't know why this happended.

Comment: There might be some specific CSS styles that affected the final result. Here is another tooltip demo. I have some adjustments to the tooltip position. You may have a try!

https://github.com/yiskang/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/bim360-iot-connected/bim360assets/wwwroot/js/BIM360IotConnectedExtension.js#L339

Comment: demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWJwR.png

Comment: BTW, if the tooltip is offset while zooming the camera, then it's expected, since the projection of the sensor position in the browser viewport is changed. So, you redo the `worldToClient()` again to get a new 2D position projection in the browser viewport for the sensor sprite viewable to adjust the tooltip postion.

Comment: Not works too. Is the value you convert in `worldToClient(value)` is the initial setup for Sprite position or a calculation using bounding box  ? because I don't see it in your reference code.

Comment: Yes, it's the initial Sprite position and also the bounding box of the MEP equipment.

Comment: See https://github.com/yiskang/forge-bim360-assets.viewer/blob/bim360-iot-connected/bim360assets/wwwroot/js/BIM360IotConnectedExtension.js#L389

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by `const viewable = viewables.find((v) => v.dbId === targetDbId)` and get its position `viewable.position` rather than using bounding box.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your good news :)